# Functionality of close not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have multiple buttons in the project, which opens multiple sidepanels.
If we click plus icon it would open the sidepanel, which can be closed using minus icon as well as the close button on the sidepanel.

Icon would toggle to minus and plus.

But when I click on the second plus icon the second panel opens, but the first panel doesn't close - it just gets covered by the second panel.

Please see the JSfiddle for it.
https://jsfiddle.net/bob_js/cpagL7qz/1/

HTML

```
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign cd-btn-a abc"></i>
<div class="container">
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign cd-btn"></i>
</div>
<div class="cd-panel from-right"> 
            <header class="cd-panel-header">
                <a href="#0" class="cd-panel-close"></a>
            </header>
            <div class="cd-panel-container">
        Content
  </div>
</div>
<div class="cd-panel-a from-right"> 
            <header class="cd-panel-header">
                <a href="#0" class="cd-panel-close"></a>
            </header>
            <div class="cd-panel-container color">
        Content
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.color{
  background-color: green !important;
}
.glyphicon-plus-sign, .glyphicon-minus-sign{
  top: 30%;
    position: absolute !important;
    z-index: 1; 
    color: rgb(255, 133, 102);
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
.glyphicon-plus-sign:hover, .glyphicon-minus-sign:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
    transform: scale(1.3);
}
*, *::after, *::before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*::after, *::before {
  content: '';
}

a {
  color: #89ba2c;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.cd-main-content {
  text-align: center;
}
.cd-main-content .cd-btn {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #89ba2c;
  color: #000;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
.no-touch .cd-main-content .cd-btn:hover {
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.cd-main-content .cd-btn-val {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #89ba2c;
  color: #000;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
.no-touch .cd-main-content .cd-btn-val:hover {
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.cd-panel {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: visibility 0s 0.6s;
  -moz-transition: visibility 0s 0.6s;
  transition: visibility 0s 0.6s;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  z-index: 9;
}
.cd-panel::after {
  /* overlay layer */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.3s 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: background 0.3s 0.3s;
  transition: background 0.3s 0.3s;
}
.cd-panel.is-visible {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transition: visibility 0s 0s;
  -moz-transition: visibility 0s 0s;
  transition: visibility 0s 0s;
}
.cd-panel.is-visible::after {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  -webkit-transition: background 0.3s 0s;
  -moz-transition: background 0.3s 0s;
  transition: background 0.3s 0s;
}
.cd-panel.is-visible .cd-panel-close::before {
  -webkit-animation: cd-close-1 0.6s 0.3s;
  -moz-animation: cd-close-1 0.6s 0.3s;
  animation: cd-close-1 0.6s 0.3s;
}
.cd-panel.is-visible .cd-panel-close::after {
  -webkit-animation: cd-close-2 0.6s 0.3s;
  -moz-animation: cd-close-2 0.6s 0.3s;
  animation: cd-close-2 0.6s 0.3s;
}


@-webkit-keyframes cd-close-1 {
  0%, 50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes cd-close-1 {
  0%, 50% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(0);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
}
@keyframes cd-close-1 {
  0%, 50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0);
    -o-transform: rotate(0);
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes cd-close-2 {
  0%, 50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes cd-close-2 {
  0%, 50% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(0);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
}
@keyframes cd-close-2 {
  0%, 50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0);
    -o-transform: rotate(0);
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
}
.cd-panel-header {
  position: fixed;
  height: 27px;
  width: 3%;
  background-color: transparent;
  z-index: 2;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transition: top 1.3s 0s;
  -moz-transition: top 1.3s 0s;
  transition: top 1.3s 0s;
}
.from-right .cd-panel-header, .from-left .cd-panel-header {
  top: -50px;
}
.from-right .cd-panel-header {
  right: 20px;
}
.from-left .cd-panel-header {
  left: 0;
}
.is-visible .cd-panel-header {
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transition: top 1.3s 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: top 1.3s 0.3s;
  transition: top 1.3s 0.3s;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1471px) {
  .cd-panel-header {
    height: 30px;
  }
}

.cd-panel-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 40px;
  /* image replacement */
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-indent: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.cd-panel-close::before, .cd-panel-close::after {
  /* close icon created in CSS */
  position: absolute;
  top: 11px;
  left: 20px;
  height: 3px;
  width: 15px;
  background-color: #fff;
  /* this fixes a bug where pseudo elements are slighty off position */
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.cd-panel-close::before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.cd-panel-close::after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.no-touch .cd-panel-close:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
}
.no-touch .cd-panel-close:hover::before, .no-touch .cd-panel-close:hover::after {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
  -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
.no-touch .cd-panel-close:hover::before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(220deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(220deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(220deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(220deg);
  transform: rotate(220deg);
}
.no-touch .cd-panel-close:hover::after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(135deg);
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}

.cd-panel-container {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  background: #901818;
  border-left: 1px solid #c8cacc;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
  -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 1.8s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 1.8s;
  transition-duration: 1.8s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition-delay: 0.3s;
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.from-right .cd-panel-container {
  right: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
}
.from-left .cd-panel-container {
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
}
.is-visible .cd-panel-container {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition-delay: 0.3s;
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .cd-panel-container {
    width: 30.5%;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1271px) {
  .cd-panel-container {
    width: 23.5%;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1471px) {
  .cd-panel-container {
    width: 23.5%;
  }
}
```

jQuery

```
$(".glyphicon-minus-sign, .glyphicon-plus-sign").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("glyphicon-minus-sign glyphicon-plus-sign");
});


jQuery(function($){
    //open the lateral panel
    $('.cd-btn').on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.cd-panel').toggleClass('is-visible');
    });
    //close the lateral panel
    $('.cd-panel').on('click', function(event){
        if( $(event.target).is('.cd-panel') || $(event.target).is('.cd-panel-close') ) { 
            $('.cd-panel').removeClass('is-visible');
            $('.cd-btn').toggleClass("glyphicon-minus-sign glyphicon-plus-sign");
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});

jQuery(function($){
    //open the lateral panel
    $('.cd-btn-a').on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.cd-panel-a').toggleClass('is-visible');
    });
    //close the lateral panel
    $('.cd-panel-a').on('click', function(event){
        if( $(event.target).is('.cd-panel-a') || $(event.target).is('.cd-panel-close') ) { 
            $('.cd-panel-a').removeClass('is-visible');
            $('.cd-btn-a').toggleClass("glyphicon-minus-sign glyphicon-plus-sign");
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: It seems to be working correctly.

Comment: @ScottMarcus no it doesn't, the problem is when opening second menu the first one doesn't close.

Comment: @KevinKloet Ah, I misunderstood the question. I have edited it to be more clear.

Comment: Maybe you could give more context in the question title, thats first.
About the other, wouldn't be simpler if there is one single click event which closes all .cd-panels and then opens the chosen one?

Comment: my bad for not being clear, @KevinKloet is right. Thats exactly is my problem. Second icon when clicked, the first would not go back to minus and vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the updated **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cpagL7qz/5/)**

You need to check it in the JS:

```
$(".glyphicon-minus-sign, .glyphicon-plus-sign").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("glyphicon-minus-sign glyphicon-plus-sign");
});


jQuery(function($){
    //open the lateral panel
    $('.cd-btn').on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.cd-panel').toggleClass('is-visible');
    // CHECKING ICON OF .cd-btn-a
    if($('.cd-btn-a').hasClass('glyphicon-minus-sign')) {
       $('.cd-btn-a').toggleClass('glyphicon-minus-sign glyphicon-plus-sign');
       $('.cd-panel-a').removeClass('is-visible');
     }
    });
    //close the lateral panel
    $('.cd-panel').on('click', function(event){
        if( $(event.target).is('.cd-panel') || $(event.target).is('.cd-panel-close') ) { 
            $('.cd-panel').removeClass('is-visible');
            $('.cd-btn').toggleClass("glyphicon-minus-sign glyphicon-plus-sign");
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});

jQuery(function($){
    //open the lateral panel
    $('.cd-btn-a').on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.cd-panel-a').toggleClass('is-visible');
    // CHECKING ICON OF .cd-btn
    if($('.cd-btn').hasClass('glyphicon-minus-sign')) {
       $('.cd-btn').toggleClass('glyphicon-minus-sign glyphicon-plus-sign');
       $('.cd-panel').removeClass('is-visible');
     }
    });
    //close the lateral panel
    $('.cd-panel-a').on('click', function(event){
        if( $(event.target).is('.cd-panel-a') || $(event.target).is('.cd-panel-close') ) { 
            $('.cd-panel-a').removeClass('is-visible');
            $('.cd-btn-a').toggleClass("glyphicon-minus-sign glyphicon-plus-sign");
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi @saurav in case if I have more than two sidepanels like the below update [Fiddle] (https://jsfiddle.net/bob_js/cpagL7qz/13/).
Could you please help

Comment: @Bob You just need to increase your conditions, thats it. Have a look at the updated fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/cpagL7qz/14/

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add an additional if statement onclick of the icons, to check whether the other panels are visible or not(using your `is-visible` class). Modify your code to this

```
$('.cd-btn').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.cd-panel').toggleClass('is-visible');
    // added below 3 lines
    if($('.cd-panel-a').hasClass('is-visible')) {
      $('.cd-panel-a').removeClass('is-visible');
    }
});

$('.cd-btn-a').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.cd-panel-a').toggleClass('is-visible');
    // added below 3 lines
    if($('.cd-panel').hasClass('is-visible')) {
       $('.cd-panel').removeClass('is-visible');
    }
});
```

[Your Fiddle updated](https://jsfiddle.net/cpagL7qz/4/)

Comment: Hey @Nikhil, that I have already achieved in my project. But here if you can see as I click first icon it changes from plus to minus and then if second icon is clicked it would not change the first icon to plus again.

Comment: Nope, the place where you added (I assume its `$('.cd-panel-a').on('click',`) is not even being rendered on the page, hence its not even being called.